# Visualforce Date formatting

Tags: visualforce, formatting, outputtext

I need this date format in a visualforce page: "December 14, 2013". I can't seem to find the format options for visualforce. I read that it's the same as the java messageformat class options, but I cannot find a list for that either.

A little help would be much appreciated

Comment: Look at the [JavaDocs for SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for the various date formats.

Comment: Good link Peter. Ive updated my answer with it.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

This will print the date out in the format **December 14, 2013**. The documentation can be found [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_outputText.htm)

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, date, MMMM d','  yyyy}">
    <apex:param value="{!contact.Birthdate}" /> 
</apex:outputText>
```

or if all you need is the current date printed out in that format then you can use this:

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, date, MMMM d','  yyyy}">
    <apex:param value="{!NOW()}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

Have a look at the [JavaDocs for SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for the various date formats. (Thanks to @PeterKnolle for the correct link)

Comment: When a date is being passed to the param, how is that transformed? The docs for `apex:param` say only strings, numbers, and booleans can be used. How is the date transformed into one of those values? I'm assuming it's miliseconds since Jan 1, 1970

Answer (score 11):

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}">
    <apex:param value="{!contact.Birthdate}" /> 
</apex:outputText>
```

link to full doc: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputText.htm

Comment: Yeah I had this link, but it doesn't show all the options and the link to the java docs is broken. Thank you though!

Comment: Is it possible to add the 'th' or 'st' after the date day numeral?

Answer (score -2):

```
<apex:outputText value=" {0,date,EEE MMM d, yyyy}">
    <apex:param value="{!a.CreatedDate}"/>
</apex:outputText>
```

**Output :** Fri July 22, 2016

This will eliminate the time from date field

Comment: this was not the format the OP asked for help with