# Populate Day value in apex:output using javascript

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery, outputfield

I am trying to populate day of date in a list of SObject using JavaScript.
[image]

I have written logic for getting day it works fine. Now I have to set Day.
Page-block table Day column code is

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!IndividualSessionrap}" var="ffs" title="PageBlock Tab">
   <apex:column style="width:20px" headerValue="Sr No">       
      <apex:outputText value="{!ffs.session.Sr_No__c}"/>
   </apex:column>
   <apex:column style="width:250px" headerValue="Day">
      <apex:outputText id="day" value="{!ffs.session.Session_Day__c}"/>
   </apex:column>
   <apex:column style="width:230px;"  headerValue="Start Date/Time">
      <apex:input id="dateField" onChange="populateDay('{!$Component.dateField}','{!$Component.day}');return false;" type="date" value="{!ffs.startDate}"/>
   </apex:column>
```

JQuery for the code is

```
document.getElementById(DayId).value('Thursday');
```

This doesnt set the value for day.

Comment: That JavaScript expression looks more like raw DOM access than jQuery: think you are accidentally mixing the two.

Comment: Yeah Keith. I am not confident about JQuery. So sometime I prefer to insert javascript expressions ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the day of the week from a date using date formatting in your `outputText` panel without any Javascript. See [Visualforce Date formatting](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22321/visualforce-date-formatting).

```visualforce
<apex:outputText value="{0, date, EEEE}">
    <apex:param value="{!myDateValue}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

If you want to use jQuery correctly, you should use it to select the element you want, then call `text('value')`. Since you are using an `outputText`, then its id is going to end with (`$=`) the value you specify (`"day"`). Because you are specifying these ids in a loop, you need to find the closest table row and then look within that for the correct `outputText` element.

Don't forget to include jQuery in your page. I usually just pull it from CDN.

```javascript
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    (function ($) {
        "use strict";
        var days = [
            "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
        ];
        $(function () {
            $('[id$="dateField"]').change(function () {
                var $this = $(this),
                    date = new Date($this.val()),
                    day = days[date.getDay()];
                $this.closest('tr').find('[id$="day"]').text(day);
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37014/discussion-between-adrian-larson-and-sfdc-shaikh).