# Changing date format on the email template

Tags: email-template

I have added a field called  Desired Ship Date on to my email template. when I tested the email template the  Desired Ship Date is being shown in the following format "Desired Ship Date: Thu Sep 29 00:00:00 GMT 2016 " but I need it to be displayed in different format like "Desired Ship Date: Thu Sep 29 2016 ". Is there a way I can do it. If yes, Can you let me know how.

Comment: What type is your email template (HTML or Visualforce)?

Comment: It is a VF template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best bet is to use `<apex:outputField />` to display your value. This will use the User's date preferences for formatting. If you cannot use that because you are not working with an sObject, see this: [Visualforce Date formatting](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22321/visualforce-date-formatting)