# Datetime to Date to String

Tags: apex, integration, date, datetime

```
Datetime Createddate = system.now();
Datetime Duedate = Class.Method(Createddate,10);
//Converting to date format
Objinstance.Field__c= Date.newinstance( dueDate.month(), dueDate.day(),dueDate.year());
Date DueDateformatted = Duedate.Date();
//convert Date to string
String DateString = DueDateformatted.format();
```

My requirement is 
Created Date = In datetime
Due Date = Date format in VF Page field 
But need to send String through integration .

`Format()` in Date Date class - Does it allow formatting in specific format like Datetime class ? I tried out but didn't work for me.

Ay suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to specify a particular format (not just the default for your locale), leave it as `Datetime`. That type has a `format` method signature which accepts a `String`. You can supply any supported [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
String iso8601 = Datetime.now().format('yyyy-MM-dd');
```

You can save it as a `Date` in the database and then create a `Datetime` instance to format for your integration.

```
String iso8601 = Datetime.newInstance(myDateField, Time.newInstance(0,0,0,0)).format(...);
```

If you just care about formatting the output in `Visualforce`, you can use the `<apex:outputText>` tag as outlined in [Visualforce Date formatting](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22321/visualforce-date-formatting).

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, date, MMMM d','  yyyy}">
    <apex:param value="{!myRecord.SomeDateField__c}" /> 
</apex:outputText>
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian . But I also have a requirement to display the field as Date . In that case what would be the best practice? Creating two different fields ? Date and String ?

Comment: @Vanilla_Sky See the updated answer. You can convert a `Date` instance to `Datetime` in order to get more flexibility in formatting. If you're going to store it, store it as a `Date`.

Comment: @Vanilla_Sky Any remaining questions?

Comment: My ideal flow of formatting would be like Datetime (returned as a value from a method call) -->Assign to a Date field of an object to display on VF Page --->Format YYYY-MM-DD and convert to string . I guess the second part will not be possible with Date type? Right now I am assigning Datetime formatted to YYYY-MM-DD to a string field additionally-  But that's not a good practice I suppose.

Comment: @Vanilla_Sky See updates for VF formatting. Store the actual `Date` or `Datetime` value. The database shouldn't be concerned with formatting.