# Trying to format date time field and display in HTML table in salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

I trying to format "ActivityDateTime" field of Events in apex and trying to display it in html table in lightning using below code:

```
 Event[] nextMeets = [select Id,Subject,ActivityDateTime,ActivityDate from Event where id in :eventIdSet and ActivityDate > today order by ActivityDate asc];        

    for(Event ev : nextMeets){

        String dateformat = ev.ActivityDateTime.format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
        system.debug('checkdatetime' + dateformat);

         DateTime dtConverted  = Datetime.valueof(dateformat);

        System.debug('##dateInStringStringfinal - '+dtConverted);
        ev.ActivityDateTime = dtConverted;
        system.debug('checkdatefiaaalll' + ev.ActivityDateTime);
        FinalNextMeets.add(ev);
        }
```

Here in the debug logs the value of the field "ActivityDateTime" is coming properly formatted like :

```
 ##dateInStringStringfinal - 2017-03-30 17:40:00
  checkdatefiaaalll2017-03-30 17:40:00
```

But when i displayed it on Html table using below code:

```
<tr>
    <td class="slds-truncate slds-cell-wrap"> {!cell.ActivityDateTime}  </td>
</tr>
```

its display like this : `2017-03-23T23:31:00.000Z`

Comment: Ideally you should use a wrapper class and display data from it.

Answer (score 1):

This question is essentially a duplicate of: [Visualforce Date formatting](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22321/visualforce-date-formatting)

That said, in this case, you should be able to put the following inside your table cell:

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, date, yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}">
    <apex:param value="{!cell.ActivityDateTime}" /> 
</apex:outputText>
```

You should be able to use any supported [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Whats what Adrain, we cannot use any apex tag in lightning..i.e u cannot use apex:outputText here, thanks.